# Flurry of blows with heavy weapon

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

Can a monk use a flurry of blows after committing the attack with heavy/two-handed weapons?

> Immediately after you take the Attack action on your
>   turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make two unarmed
>   strikes as a bonus action.

Answer (score 7):

D&D5 says what it means and means what it says.

1. Take an Attack action
2. Spend Ki point
3. Make two unarmed strikes as a bonus action.

You can use the Attack action to hit people with an elephant if you want.

Comment: Assuming a Storm Giant monk!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie ... or a dwarf elephant.