# Can a monk use Flurry of Blows without meeting the requirements of the Martial Arts feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, unarmed-combat

The [Martial Arts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/monk#MartialArts) feature gives a monk the ability to use Dexterity instead of Strength with unarmed strikes and monk weapons. It also gives the monk the ability to make an additional unarmed strike as a bonus action. A monk must be unarmed or wielding only monk weapons to use Martial Arts.

The [Ki](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/monk#Ki) feature gives a monk the ability to spend one Ki point to use Flurry of Blows, which lets the monk make two additional uarmed strikes as a bonus action.

If a monk is wielding a weapon that is not a monk weapon (ignoring the question of whether it is wise for the monk to do this), can s/he still spend a Ki point to make two additional unarmed strikes as a bonus action? If so, must the unarmed strikes use Strength rather than Dexterity? I believe that the answer to both is yes, but am I missing something?

Comment: [Related] [Can any attack action trigger Flurry of Blows?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73803), [What are the restrictions of an unarmed strike?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47537)

Comment: @MikeQ: I think this might actually be a duplicate of that first question you linked.